# About Facebook Login Procedure

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

i am a new in facebook application.

i will make a server(google app engine) and client(android application).

As a facebook perspective, both my server and client are acutally client.

Anyway, server and android application both need login.

is there something to login both (server and client) only in a one action??

in conclusion, i want a way to login two client, using only one login action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After logging in a user you are given an access token. You could share this token between both your applications, al long as they use the same facebook app (app-secret and app-id).